# Apache Server File Permission

Tags: ajax, apache, apache-config

I am using Apache Server 6.0 and I am trying to update a file using ajax put request but the server is giving me error 405 Method Not Allowed. I am working this out on windows.
Can anybody help me out if that.

Thanks in Advance.

Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using apache tomcat (because you have mentioned version 6.0)

In that case add this to your webapp's web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myDefault</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value> <!-- this will enable PUT for your app -->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myDefault</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can test this like so, to upload the file (You need the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) program to test)

```
curl -T somefile.txt http://localhot:8080/<yourapp>/
```

If you want to enable this globally, you can make the same change in /conf/web.xml (for default servlet)